# Elixir - Dynamically access object property using variable

Tags: object, elixir

I am trying to access an object property using variable with Elixir, but when I try using x[:variable], it seems that it doesn`t reconize as a variable, but indicates that I am trying to access de property "variable"

Someone can help?

```
  def currencyConverter({ from, to, amount }) do
    exchangeRate = currencies[:from]
    ...
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming here that `currencies` is a map, there's not really anything called an object in Elixir.

`:from` is a symbol, totally unrelated to the variable `from`. You should just do `currencies[from]`. You can also use `Map.get/3` or `Map.fetch/2` to handle the case when the key is missing from the `currencies` map.

Comment: Yeah.. sorry, currencies is a map like this:
%{
      BRL: %{
        currency: "Brazilian Real",
        rate: %{
          AED: 0.699986,
          AFN: 14.512400,
        }
      }
    }

But if i try to access currencies[from], I obtain nil (assuming that from is BRL)

Comment: Can you make sure from is actually `:BRL` atom instead of String `"BRL"` ?

Comment: @RafaelPolonio but please, do not use `String.to_atom/1`. Never use that function.

Comment: Another solution would be to change the format of `currencies` so that the keys are strings.